# GIT 1.8.5 shows: "BUG: There are unmerged index entries"

Tags: windows, git, merge, msysgit

I am using GIT 1.8.5.2.msysgit.0 (latest download version from git-scm.com)and getting this message during merge.

I have run the merge using recommended GIT_MERGE_VERBOSITY=5. Maybe there is one suspicious entry:

> CONFLICT (rename/rename): Rename "xxx"->"yyy" in branch "Temporary
>   merge branch 1" rename "xxx"->"yyy" in "Temporary merge branch 2"
>   (left unresolved)

But I don't know. All other conflicts are content, add/add or rename/rename but this is the only one showing "left unresolved". The file and directory "xxx" does not exist anymore on both branch sides. I tried to solve the problem by creating the file "xxx". But the BUG message comes up again and above message.

Sorry, that I cannot post the complete output and that I have to replace filenames with XXX and YYY because I this repository is used in my work and I can't give more information up to now.

Maybe someone has some more information on how I can proceed here?

**Edit:** I found a workaround to get the merge finished without this BUG message by adding the option -X rename-threshold=95%.

```
git merge --no-ff --no-commit -X rename-threshold=95% branch_to_merge_from
```

Comment: What is it that you are trying to do?

Comment: @Thomas: I run the command **git merge --no-ff --no-commit branch_to_merge_from**

Comment: Have the same problem, any other suggestions?